# How @JvmOverloads work on Kotlin when using default arguments?

Tags: android, kotlin, overloading, default-arguments

I want to understand how to use JvmOverloads annotation better and how to handle kotlin default arguments in java in a better way.

Imagine I have a function like this:

```
@JvmOverloads
@JvmStatic
fun testFunction(age: Int, name: String = "", level: Int = 0, class: String = "")
```

The kotlin bytecode generates:

```
   @JvmStatic
   @JvmOverloads
   public static final void testFunction(int age, @NotNull String name, int level) {
      testFunction$default(age, name, level, (String)null, 8, (Object)null);
   }

   @JvmStatic
   @JvmOverloads
   public static final void testFunction(int age, @NotNull String name) {
      testFunction$default(age, name, 0, (String)null, 12, (Object)null);
   }

   @JvmStatic
   @JvmOverloads
   public static final void testFunction(int age) {
      testFunction$default(age, (String)null, 0, (String)null, 14, (Object)null);
   }
```

Which means I can call

```
testFunction(0)
testFunction(0, "John")
testFunction(0, "John", 1)
testFunction(0, "John", 1, "Warrior")
```

But I CANNOT call a function like this in java code:

`testFunction(0,1)`

But in kotlin would be possible! Since name and class have default values.

Could I get some help? How does this work? Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. `@JvmOverloads` only generates overloads for default parameter values from last to first. Not all possible combinations. It can't do that, because there would be conflicting signatures. For example, if there was a method with only your `age` parameter and only your `level` parameter, how would Java know which one to call?

You can tinker with this by changing the parameter order. So if you need a method with `level` and `age` parameters, but no `name`, you can put those two parameters first in the Kotlin function.

Answer (score -1):

> testFunction(0,1)

> But in kotlin would be possible!

Actually, it would not:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments

> You are also able to skip specific arguments with default values, rather than omitting them all. However, after the first skipped argument, you must name all subsequent arguments:

So you would have to do:

```
testFunction(0, level = 1)
```

> Could I get some help?

With what?

> How does this work?

You already showed that you used the `@JvmOverloads` and that you can see the bytecode generated. That's how it works.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/

> Am I using it wrong?

Not necessarily. But if your desire is to be able to do `testFunction(0, 1)` then you have to change the declared order of the parameters of the function:

```
@JvmOverloads
@JvmStatic
fun testFunction(age: Int, level: Int = 0, name: String = "", class: String = "")
```

Then your `testFunction(0, 1)` would work in both Java and Kotlin (without a named argument).